# pyspark memory-efficient loop to add indicator columns to dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Is there a way to convert the following into code that takes advantage of pyspark parallelization in the `for` loop?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

my_list_of_integers = list(df_column_of_integers.select('column_name').toPandas()['column_name'])

for my_int in my_list_of_integers:    
    temp_df = large_df1.filter(large_df1.a_value_column == my_int)
    temp_df = temp_df.select("a_key_column")
    temp_df = temp_df.withColumn("indicator" + str(my_int), F.lit(1))
    large_df2 = large_df2.join(temp_df, on="a_key_column", how="left")
```

After going through the `for` loop 7 times (the goal was 185), the code fails and gives this error message:

`org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 52 bytes of memory, got 0`

An additional error message that is reported from the system I am working in suggests how to resolve the issue:

> **Your job has exceeded the memory overhead. Your code might be attempting to run wholly on one executor, which can happen if you haven't used pySpark; for instance if you're using Pandas or UDFs.**

***For a simple, working example***, here is sample input and a visualization of the expected output from this sample input:

Sample input:

```
df_column_of_integers = spark.createDataFrame([10, 11, 13], IntegerType()).toDF('column_name')

df1_key_column = [52, 52, 53, 53, 52, 52]
a_value_column = [9, 13, 10, 11, 12, 10]
large_df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(df1_key_column, a_value_column), schema=['a_key_column', 'a_value_column'])

large_df2 = spark.createDataFrame([52, 54, 53], IntegerType()).toDF('a_key_column')
```

Expected output (i.e., the final version of large_df2 for the simple example above):

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+                                                              
|  a_key_column|  indicator10|  indicator11|  indicator13|
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|            52|            1|         NULL|            1|
|            54|         NULL|         NULL|         NULL|
|            53|            1|            1|         NULL|
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

***In actuality***, my df_column_of_integers has 185 entries. large_df1 has 82 million rows and 2 columns before it is filtered in the first step of the `for` loop, and at most 0.9 million rows after that filter.  large_df2 starts with 0.9 million rows and 33 columns (23 of which are Integers). From the detailed error message, it seems the error is occurring during the join.  However, I have joined larger datasets on this system in past, just not in a `for` loop on a Pandas list, so it makes me think the source of the issue is the use of a Pandas list which prompts the use of a single executor. Thus, I am thinking that there might be a better loop technique that someone might know.

I tried using .foreach with a lambda function, as described here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-loop-iterate-through-rows-in-dataframe/, but I cannot figure out how to add large_df1 and large_df2 as additional inputs to the lambda function. And I don't think .map would be helpful, because I don't want to edit my_list_of_integers, only interate over its values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: - If your question is about to optimize the spark code to add indicator columns to dataframe then you should post the input and expected output as well
- If your question is about to improve parallelization for the for loop then I'd say your for loop is totally fine as it, there is no action in there, Spark Catalyst will optimize it in its way

Comment: Thank you @pltc , I think my question is mostly about how to improve the parallelization. Please see my additional description of the apparent issues above; does this description help?  Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hi @pltc, I have now added a small example with sample input and a visualization of the output I expect it would produce. Thank you for your help thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: I replaced everything within the `for` loop with:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

large_df1 = large_df1.filter(large_df1.a_value_column.isin(my_list_of_integers))
large_df1 = large_df1.withColumn("my_value". F.lit(1))
large_df1 = large_df1.groupBy("a_key_column").pivot("a_value_column", my_list_of_integers).agg(F.first(F.col("my_value")))
large_df2 = large_df2.join(large_df1, on="a_key_column", how="left")
```

The key step is the use of `pivot`. The new code runs easily and quickly.